# useState hooks wont work or not triggered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This my post component working.req function working on mounted and when the onScroll function triggered but hooks not work or never triggered.Always value of page 1

```
const PostsComponent = () => {
  const [totalPage, setTotalPage] = useState(1)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);
  const [haveMore, setHaveMore] = useState(null)
  const { items } = useSelector(state => ({
    items: state.posts.items
  }));
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const req = () => {
    if (page <= totalPage) {
      setLoading(true)
      getPosts(page).then(res => {
        res.posts.map(item => dispatch(getterPosts(item)));
        res.posts.length > 0 ? setHaveMore(true) : setHaveMore(false)
        setTotalPage(Math.ceil(res.total / 6));
      }).finally(f => setLoading(false), setPage(page + 1));
    }
  };

  const onScroll = event => {
    const { scrollHeight, scrollTop, offsetHeight } = event.srcElement;
    if (scrollTop + offsetHeight === scrollHeight) {
      req();
    }
  };

};
```

getPosts function from services

```
export const getPosts = page => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios
      .get(`${BASE_URL}/api/posts?page=${page}`)
      .then(res => resolve(res.data))
      .catch(err => reject(err.response.data.message));
  });
};
```

Comment: FWIW, `res.posts.length > 0 ? setHaveMore(true) : setHaveMore(false)` is a fairly roundabout way to write `setHaveMore(res.posts.length > 0)`... ;-)

Comment: thank you more clear.

Comment: FWIW, using the conditional operator as a statement and using the comma operator in an arrow function's concise expression are both anti-patterns (not least because what you're doing with the arrow function above won't work). I noted above how you can fix the conditional operator thing in this particular case, but in the general case where you're doing two different things, just use an `if`. On the arrow function thing, just use the function body form and proper statements within it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. Your `page` variable can be stale by the time you're using it, because your component may have re-rendered prior to the `finally` callback.
2. This line doesn't do what you presumably want it to do:

   ```
   }).finally(f => setLoading(false), setPage(page + 1))
   ```

   What that does is **call** `setPage(page + 1)`, and then call `finally` passing in the function `f => setLoading(false)` and the value `undefined` (the result of calling `setPage`). This is one of the many reasons not to use the comma operator in order to use the concise form of arrow function.

You can fix them by

1. Using the callback version of `setPage`, which always receives the current value of the state item
2. Using the function body form of the arrow function, containing the two calls you want to make in the `finally` handler

Like this:

```
}).finally(f => {
    setLoading(false);
    setPage(p => p + 1);
});
```

---

I recommend reading [this article](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) by Dan Abramov. Ostensibly, it's about `useEffect`, but along the way he explains things like stale state variables really well...

Comment: @Erkançalışkan - Please update your question with a runnable [mcve] demonstrating the problem using  Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). Having said that, I just noticed a second problem with your `finally` call and updated the answer. But I wouldn't expect that second problem to mean `page` didn't get updated.